# how to change BackColor/ForeColor of a single cell in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm trying to set the ForeColor of a Cell in `ObjectListView`. There are questions and answer about this in SO and other websites, that suggesting to use `FormatCell` event of `ObjectListView`. as it is documented in http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-change-the-colours-of-a-row-or-just-a-cell

I tried the code and it works, however it works when cells needs to be redrawn (they appear black at first and each Item I move the mouse over it the event is called). but I don't really need an Event as I want to set a fixed color like:

```
 foreach (OLVListItem item in olv.Items)
      if (item.SubItems[7].Text != "")
      {
          if (item.SubItems[7].Text.StartsWith("-"))
              item.SubItems[7].ForeColor = Color.Red;
          else item.SubItems[7].ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
      }
```

but the above code doesn't effect the results.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer accidentally going through it's properties. I'm adding this as answer so that it may help others.
`OLVListItem` has a property `UseItemStyleForSubItems` which is `true` by default which uses same Font, ForeColor and BackColor of the `ObjectListView` for its items. setting its value to false worked:

```
foreach (OLVListItem item in olv.Items)
      if (item.SubItems[7].Text != "")
      {
         item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
          if (item.SubItems[7].Text.StartsWith("-"))
              item.SubItems[7].ForeColor = Color.Red;
          else item.SubItems[7].ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
      }
```

Comment: I do not understand why using FormatCell did not work for you as stated in the question. This solution is pretty dirty, as it would break when column order is changed and it doesn't use the actual model object to check the condition which is discouraged when using OLV.